# Disable docker md5sum with custom image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to modify a public image, and create a new image with my changes, but when I try to run a container with my new custom image it triggers a md5sum and deletes some of my changes, is it possible to disable the md5sum?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM public-image:latest

COPY . /dir

RUN sh my-script.sh
```

my-script.sh is to copy files to different locations, one of the files I modify is constants.json but it triggers the md5sum and reverts the changes

[image: That's what shows when I run a new container with the custom image]

Comment: Can you describe the problem clearly? Tell us what have you done and what do you expected and the actual result

Comment: @HarryCoder I updated the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the image I was using is based on confd, this is a management tool that can be configure to do md5sum in configurarion files, I just deleted the original configuration files from the confd folder